# Problema con sesiones en un INDEX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, aplicación-web

Tengo un login donde ingreso mis credenciales y me redirecciona al dashboard en un index.php que dejare el codigo a continuación. Pero antes, mi problema en particular es que cuando recargo la pagina desde la barra de busqueda, la sesion se cierra y me envia denuevo al login en vez de traerme el dashboard denuevo.

Algo me hace sospechar que la sesion se destruye.

```php
<?php
include_once 'includes/user.php';
include_once 'includes/user_session.php';

$errorLogin = "";

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    $user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());
    include_once 'dashboard.php';

}else if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    
    $userForm = $_POST['username'];
    $passForm = $_POST['password'];
    
    $userSession = new UserSession();
    $user = new User();
    if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm)){
        // Grant access
        $userSession->setCurrentUser($userForm);
        $user->setUser($userForm);
        include_once 'dashboard.php';
    }else{ 
        // Deny Access
        $errorLogin = "Credenciales inválidas";
        include_once 'login.php';
    }
}else{
    $userSession = new UserSession();
    $user = new User();
    include_once 'login.php';
}
?>
```

Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Estás trabajando con sesiones, pero no veo `session_start();` por ningún lado. Si no forma parte del código en index.php es recomendable que sea lo primero que añadas al primer bloque de php que tengas en ese archivo.

Answer (score 0):

En cada archivo php que use la sesion. debes iniciarlas.
en cada archivo php al principio. agrega lo siguiente.

```
session_start();
```

Cuando ya no uses las sesiones. destruyelas con:

```
session_destroy();
```